# SQL Query between three dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2008, datetime

I just wanted to see if there was any better way to do an query like this, I think that the cast in the where clause is the bottleneck but not sure what is the best way to fix it. Execution plan has the 34% is the insert into the temp table and 42% is the Hash match.

```
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + -12, 0)
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

where cast(ITF.Date as DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@StartDate as date) 
      AND CAST(@EndDate as date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would seem to want:

```
where ITF.Date >= CAST(@StartDate as date) and
      ITF.Date < dateadd(day, 1, CAST(@EndDate as date))
```

[Aaron Bertrand's blog](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) "What do BETWEEN and the Devil Have in Common" explains quite well why you should not use `between` with date/time values.

Note adding "1" to the end date.  Your code is including the end date, as does this version.

Answer (score 1):

The most appropriate way to check if a `DATETIME` value is between two `DATE`s is to use `date1 <= datetime AND datetime < date2` where date2 is one day more than the last date that is to be included.

This won't require any casting on the datetime columns and takes care of edge cases where datetime column contains time value such as `23:59:59.999999` and avoids specific *tricks* such as subtracting 3 milliseconds hack.

```
WHERE ITF.Date >= CAST(@StartDate as date) AND ITF.Date < CAST(@EndDate as date)
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean can you please explain.

Answer (score 0):

The part of the code you have posted is fine and is not the cause of any performance issue.

If you are getting a Hash Match in your execution plan, it means you are missing one or more Indexes, probably on the columns that two tables join on.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the rest of your query, the eliminate of @StartDate and @EndDate cast would speed up your query based on my experience since SQL 6.5.

`DECLARE @StartDate Date
 DECLARE @EndDate Date`